# How to access contact list in react native app

Tags: react-native

I am developing a complete mobile CRM, as part of the development I need to access and modify contact list over the phone.

Which is the best plugin to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at React Native Contacts, found [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [expo](https://expo.io/), then you'd better use [expo-contacts](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts/). I've found it really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install `react-native-contacts` library. Run this command `npm install react-native-contacts --save` .

Then use this code

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
 // contacts returned
})
```

For specific access on `IOS` and `android` go through this link [React native contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts)

Answer (score 0):

Now, They have api that return contacts based on provided phone number, here is an example

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

  const phoneNumber = "+92123456789"; //Number could be complete and it will search 
                                      //with all the numbers from the contacts 
                                      //database and will return results accordingly. 

  Contacts.getContactsByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, (err, contacts) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('some error happended ' + err);
    } else {
      // contact is javascript object and that can have more that one contacts details
      console.log('Contact : ' + JSON.stringify(contacts));
    }
  });
```

further details can be get from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-contacts#api